# Converting a List into a Nested List in Scala

Tags: list, scala

How can I convert for example

```
List(2, 5, 24, 7, 34, 8)
```

into

```
List(2, List(5, List(24, List(7, List(34, List(8))))))
```

I guess it is about folding right but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It is not a list. They are tuples!

Comment: My bad sorry. I corrected the representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.foldRight(List[Any]())((a,b) => List(a,b))` will produce `(2, (5, (24, (7, (34, (8, Nil))))))`. If you really need the `(34, 8)` at the end, you can change the folding function to use some pattern matching.